# Seems like JS isnt loading in browser, onclick function not calling

Tags: javascript, html

I have button in HTML which calls a javascript function, or at least it is supposed to.
instead of "onclick" i have tried an event listener in JS which also didnt work.

full html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="testing.js" type="common.js"></script>
  <script src="server.mjs" type="common.js"></script>
</head>
<header></header>

<body>
  <title>hello</title>
  <form>
    <input id="inputBox" type="text" />
    <button id="submitBtn" onclick="submitToDB()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the function is contained within "testing.js" but it does not called called correctly.

```
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";

function submitToDB() {
  inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
  console.log("button pressed" + inputBox.value);
  createTable();
}
```

The large objective is to use an SQLite DB. The DB connection is working, but i cannot seem call functions from the HTML DOM.

If anyone can help, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Your JS file is a module (it has an `import` statement), and modules do not expose global symbols. Thus you can explicitly export the function as a property of `window`, or, better, you can attach the event handler in your JavaScript code with `.addEventListener()` instead of using an "onclick" attribute.

Comment: When fixed the module issue, the form will be submitted, which with this particular code causes the page to reload.

Comment: You also have `type="common.js"` on your `script` elements. That's not a standard type. Unless you load a script to explicitly handle those, indeed, nothing will do anything with the contents since you've said they aren't the default (JavaScript).

Comment: I doubt also sqlite works in a browser ..?

Comment: Summing up the comments: 1. Change `type` to `type="module"` so the browser knows you're using JavaScript standard modules, and 2. Remove the `onClick` and hook up the handler using `addEventListener`: `document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", submitToDB);`. 3. You have an `import` with no path on the module specifier (`"sqlite3"`) and you have to [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). That's an error. But as Teemu points out, `sqlite3` may not be for use in browsers (at least it doesn't [say it is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), but...).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you should try it works at my site.

```js
function submitToDB() {
  const inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
  console.log("button pressed: " + inputBox.value);
  createTable();
}

function createTable() {
  // Your code to create table
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
  </head>
  <header></header>

  <body>
    <title>hello</title>
    <form>
      <input id="inputBox" type="text" />
      <button id="submitBtn" onclick="submitToDB()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It works" is not an answer. Please explain how this actually solves the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).